# Why can I not create a button action in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

In storyboard, I created a second view, however I cannot control-drag an action for "Button" into the ViewController, whereas I am allowed to control-drag an action for the Translate button and it appears in ViewController. Why am I not allowed to assign an action for "Button" ??
[image]

Comment: You already assigned your class in Storyboard for your Controller?

Comment: @derdida I added a new View via the storyboard to an already existing project

Comment: You need to assign a class for your ViewController, so create a new ViewController Class, assign it to your ViewController in Storyboard (Custom Class / Class) and then you are able to connect it using IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are looking at the wrong class's code (on the right side of the split editor). The Button is in a view whose view controller is the ViewController class, so you can control-drag from it into the ViewController class code. But Translate is in a view whose view controller is *not* the ViewController class. So obviously Xcode is not going to let you control-drag from it into the ViewController class code; the two things have nothing to do with each other.

You need a class for this second view controller - you need a class file for it and you need to mark this view controller in the storyboard as having this class. And then that will be the class file you want to show on the right in order to control-drag to it from Translate.